# update value c++ (singgle linked listed)

Tags: c++, linked-list

i have a question. how to update value in linked listed. I have a code

```
void edit() {
node *temp;
temp = awal_ptr;
char goldar[5];
int caridata;
int ketemu=0;
if(awal_ptr != NULL) {
    cout<<"\n Input Id  Yang Akan Diedit\t: ";
    cin>>caridata;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        temp->id;
        if(caridata==temp->id) {
            cout<<">>>------------------------------<<<"<<endl;
            cout<<" Nama\t: "<<temp->nama<<endl;
            cout<<" Golongan Darah\t: "<<temp->gol<<endl;
            cout<<" ------------------------------"<<endl;
            ketemu=1;
            cout<<"Masukan Golongan Darah Baru: ";
            cin>>goldar;
            temp->id=caridata;
            temp->gol==goldar;
            //temp = temp->next;
            //temp->id=goldar;
            cout<<"Data Berhasil Diupdate"<<endl;
        } temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(ketemu==0) {
        cout<<" Data tidak ditemukan";
    }
} else cout<<" Belum ada data!";
getch();
```

}

how to update value goldar (lisked list). when i update goldar. no error but value doesnt change. example i update or edit data with id 112 form A to O. the message succes but the value doesnt change it still A. hope you can help me

Answer (score 3):

```
temp->gol==goldar;
```

Try `=` instead of `==`. You are comparing values here, not assigning.

Comment: its gives me error because goldar is char[5]. and i change goldar same to gol to char[5] but still it didnot update the data

Comment: Then maybe stop writing C code disguised as C++ and don't use `char[5]`. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Also turn on compiler warnings. It should tell you that `temp->id;` is a statement with no effect. And `if(caridata==temp->id) { ... temp->id=caridata;` has no effect as well. The `temp->gol==goldar;` should have given a warning too.

Comment: im using c++ not c. maybe you can check my full code. hope you can help me. 
https://pastebin.com/KSua2Pz8

Comment: @Xianying You are writing code like someone who knows C and knows barely any c++. Lots of C-style arrays, raw pointers, no constructors, no destructors, no methods, using conio.h, ...

Comment: sorry. im new in programming. hope you can help.

Comment: @Xianying, from the code you shared I see that you declared `gol` in your struct as `char[5]`. If there is no particular reason for that, you can change it to `string` and that should work for you.